# Behavior of setting the model and ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading the AngularJS book from O'REALLY. And in page 28, it says that we can set up the model from the template:

> Since expressions execute in the context of the controller’s scope associated with their element, setting properties in expressions is the same as setting a property of the controller’s scope.

And shown as an example:

```
<button ng-click='count=3'>...
has the same effect as:
<button ng-click='setCount()'>...
where function
CountController($scope) { $scope.setCount = function() {$scope.count=3; }}
```

So I tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = 'restaurantApp'>
<body>
<table ng-controller="restaurantTableController">
    <tr ng-repeat= 'restaurant in directory'
        ng-click = 'selectedRow = $index'
        ng-class = '{selected: $index == selectedRow}'>
        <td>{{restaurant.name}}</td>
        <td>{{restaurant.cuisine}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style>
    .selected{
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var restaurantModule = angular.module('restaurantApp',[]);
    restaurantModule.controller('restaurantTableController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectedRow = null;
        $scope.directory = [{name: 'cevichesa', cuisine: 'seafood'},
            {name: 'arnoldos', cuisine: 'pizza'}];
        $scope.selectRestaurant = function(row){
            $scope.selectedRow = row;
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The line `ng-click = 'selectedRow = $index'` is where I'm setting up the module from the view.
But the behavior is that the row clicked gets green and stays green after selecting other row.

On the other hand, if I replace this line with `ng-click = 'selectRestaurant($index)'`, the behavior is, as expected, that the clicked row gets green and fades when other row is clicked.

I don't have a clue on what is happening. Any explanation is welcomed. I would say both ways of changing `selectedRow` should work fine. But obviously I'm missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `ng-repeat` creates its own child scope, so within the repeat if you have:

```
ng-click = 'selectedRow = $index'
```

It set the `selectedRow` of the *child scope* - and leaves the parent alone. Now, if you call the function:

```
ng-click = 'selectRestaurant($index)'
$scope.selectRestaurant = function(row){
     $scope.selectedRow = row;
};
```

This refers to the `selectedRow` in the *parent scope* - thus not allowing more than 1 row to be selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So `ng-class = '{selected: $index == selectedRow}'` is looking for selectedRow in something like a chain of scopes, where the scope in ng-repeat is at the beginning.

Comment: If the `ng-class` is within the repeater, it will first check the current scope (the current iterated scope) for `selectedRow` - if not found, it'll look up the chain.